# What is the proper way of implementing threading in a GTK application?

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I am aware that this is quite a vague question, but bear with me. When trying to add threading to GTK applications, I often find my implementation to be quite cumbersome. Take an example where upon pressing a button, `example_function` gets called. This function calls other functions, performs a long calculation, then calls GTK code. Point is that this function performs a lot of different tasks.

The question is, how should a function (`example_function`) be structured? Should the entire function be moved to a separate thread, with all code that updates the UI moved into separate functions and called using `GLib.idle_add`? Or should it run on the main thread with only the long-taking code moved into a separate function, and having that threaded - if this were the case, then how should sequentiality be handled?

Take the following non-threaded function:

```
def main_function(self, widget):
    print('start of main_function')

    output = self.long_function(example_argument)
    self.button.set_label(label=output)
    print('label set')

    self.another_function()
    print('end of main_function')
```

What would be the post optimal way of adding threading to such a function, while maintaining sequentiality. Ideally, all calculations would be moved off the main UI thread.

Comment: There should be a way in GTK to do that without threading, something like a schedule that takes care for your different task. This will be a better way as using threading. Did you check **gdk_threads_add_idle**?

Comment: I have, however I have no idea how to implement it, since the documentation for it is not in Python (so I can't really understand it).

Comment: Also, isn't `threads_add_idle` supposed to be deprecated? The documentation specifically says to use replace `Gdk.threads_add_idle` with `GLib.idle_add` calls.

Comment: Could be that is depraced but if you read the docs you will find an alternative. The problem with pyhton's threading is that it can become very fast complicated. So I recommend to use frameworks own thread/idle/...